# Stainless or aluminum chimney liner

Tags: chimney

We replaced our oil burner with natural gas (not the high efficiency type) and it appears the cooler exhaust is causing heavy condensation near the roof. Chimney company wants to install a stainless liner but I hear aluminum is an option since this is natural gas.  Will aluminum work? Will it last?

Comment: This isn't a high efficiency model that requires pvc?

Comment: No.  Not the high efficiency type. It's a Crown Bimini

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I would consider stainless preferable in every way. However, there evidently are [UL listed aluminum liners](http://www.mtlfab.com/liners.php) for venting gas appliances. I'd still put stainless in my house (if I had a gas line on my street.)

Stainless has better corrosion resistance, higher temperature tolerance, higher strength, and some decades of experience (in general, not specifically with flexible chimney liners) of having far more fatigue and corrosion failures of aluminum items than stainless steel items.

The only reasons I would normally choose aluminum over stainless don't really apply here - better thermal conductivity and lighter weight.

Comment: Care to say why?

Comment: Corrosion, while aluminum has that oxide layer thing going for it in normal atmospheric exposure, moist environments in the presence of combustion byproducts can make it as durable as unprotected iron.